# How to use the dictionary dataype in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am facing problems with this code, Can anyone suggest what are the problems with it, I am trying to find the frequency of each element in an array

```
 Public Sub P3()
    Dim no, freq, arr(5) As Integer
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 Integer Elements : ")
    For i = 0 To 4
        arr(i) = Console.ReadLine()
    Next
    For i = 0 To 4
        no = arr(i)
        For j = 0 To 4
            If no = arr(i) Then
                freq += 1
            End If
        Next
        If dict.ContainsKey(no) Then
            dict(i) += 1
        End If
        freq = 0
    Next

    For Each ab As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) In dict
        Console.WriteLine("Frequency Of " & ab.Key, " is " & ab.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well for one you never seem to add anything to the dictionary... If `ContainsKey()` returns `False` that means that the specified item does not exist, in which case you should add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code little bit refactored:

```
Public Sub P3()
    Dim no, arr(5) As Integer
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 Integer Elements : ")
    For i = 0 To 4
        arr(i) = Console.ReadLine()
    Next
    For i = 0 To 4
        no = arr(i)
        If dict.ContainsKey(no) Then
            dict(no) += 1
        Else
            dict.Add(no, 1)
        End If
    Next

    For Each ab As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) In dict
        Console.WriteLine("Frequency Of " & ab.Key & " is " & ab.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

This loop:

```
For j = 0 To 4
    If no = arr(i) Then
        freq += 1
     End If
Next
```

is unnecessary, in outer loop we will count occurences (anyway, this way you might determine frequency, but you don't use it anyway, also you are counting it for every item separately, which is very, very inefficient).

The problem with your dictionary was, that you weren't adding any elements to it! Your if statement should look like:

```
If dict.ContainsKey(no) Then
    dict(no) += 1
Else
    dict.Add(no, 1)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks so much It Worked

Comment: @BhupeshVarshney If my answer helped you, you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TestDic()
    Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) From
    {
        {1, 100},
        {2, 200},
        {3, 100},
        {4, 70},
        {5, 200},
        {6, 300}
    }
    Dim z = dic.GroupBy(Function(k) k.Value).
            Select(Function(w) New With {.Value = w.Key, .Count = w.Count()})
    '// Dump results to ListBox
    z.ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) lstResults.Items.Add($"Value: {x.Value}, Count = {x.Count}"))
End Sub
```